# Using "to resume" as "to summarise "

Tags: meaning

can I use "resume" as a verb to mean not only "to continue" but also "to summarise"  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is a historical sense of the word that is now sufficiently rare that few if any people will understand you. I had to look it up to see if you were talking any sense at all. Unless you're going for that sort of effect, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

What country are you from? I assume Russia or another Russian-speaking country.

In English, "resume" cannot be used as "summary" (of a random story). It is a [false friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) in some languages like Romanian (rezumat) or Russian (резюме).

A CV is also called "resume" with the meaning of "summary of experience", but I never encountered this meaning in a different context.

Comment: Strictly, a CV is called a résumé, pronounced 'rezhumay'. The verb resume, pronounced 'rezhoom' means 'recommence' or 'restart'.

Comment: You are correct, but most people would not use accents for the simple fact that usually they are not present on the keyboard. Even in other printed material, the accents are usually missing - probably because of the "laziness" of the writer / editor... As a matter of fact, I saw accents associated with this word so few times, that I am not even sure how many of them should I use (and where). Of course, a dictionary is always useful. I know that ;)

Comment: On a keyboard without accented characters, the e acute character é can be obtained by holding down the ALT key, and typing 0130 on the numeric keypad